# Python 3 Nesting String format

Tags: nested, string-formatting, python-3.6

I'm trying to generate a simple triangle shape with numbers, where the output might look like this:

```
  1
 22
333
```

However, I can't get this to work with a nested String format, the best I can achieve is the following...

```
        for i in range(1, size+1):    
            line = f'{i}' *i
            print(f"{line:>{size}}")
```

Ideally, I'd like to have 'line' nested within the print method. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What do you mean by "'line' nested within the print method"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "nested" format string needs to be formatted twice. Any curly braces you want to keep for the second time needs to be escaped in the first, thus `{` becomes `{{` and `}` becomes `}}`. Also, since you can't use the `f` prefix twice, You can explicitly call `format` for the second formatting.

What you're looking for is this:

```
for i in range(1, size + 1):
    line = f"{i}" * i
    print(f"{{0:>{size}}}".format(line))
```

So first string formatting turns `f"{{0:>{size}}}"` into `{0:>3}`, thus when reaching the explicit calling of `format` you basically get `print("{0:>3}".format(line))`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually if what you want is to embed the "line" creation within the f-string itself, you can achieve it with:

```
for i in range(1, size+1):
    print(f"{str(i) * i:>{size}}")
```

Alternatively you can also form a string with the old % operator, in there, if needed.

```
for i in range(1, size+1):
    print(f"{'%s' % (i) * i:>{size}}")
```